# Travis can't find my travis.yml file

Tags: travis-ci

I have **.travis.yml** file at root directory of my repo but Travis-Ci keeps giving me message:

> Could not find .travis.yml, using standard configuration.

I don't know if it's important in my case but in my .travis.yml file:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
# command to install dependencies
install: "pip install -r requirements.txt"
script: nosetests
```

Here is my travis link: https://travis-ci.org/vgSefa/pBlog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After little bit more research and trying problem solved by itself.

I pushed some code changes and suddenly travis found my .travis.yml file. So, where is no solution, you keep working and travis fill be fine in time.

I also sent a mail to travis support, i might fix this if this is really a bug.

Comment: Hmmm, this solution doesn't make sense to me.  I already pushed several commits to the same pull request, and it keeps failing telling me I have no travis.yml file.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It does not make any sense at all. It took like two hours for me to find the yml file. Same happened to my friend too. If you can't get it to working in few hours, i suggest to send e-mail to support.